# Error Handling in Model (MVC)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, error-handling, model

I was wondering what the excepted standard is for handling errors in the Model.

Currently I have 'setError' and 'getError' methods that's in use by all my Models.

This means I'm only concerned with whether a call to a method in my Model is true or false. If it's false then I would use `$this->model->getError()` in my Controller.

Additionally I'm contemplating setting up a separate file that contains all my errors. One file per model, also wanted to have thoughts on this.

Answer (score 4):

A simpler solution would be to use [exceptions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

When an error occurs that would  be something you display to a user, throw a special kind of an exception - perhaps named `UserError`. The exception should contain the text of the error message when you throw it. These kinds of errors are *features* which provide users with useful information (i.e. they attempted to delete something that did not exist - which can happen when they have multiple browsers open, etc.)

e.g.:

```
throw new UserError("That object no longer exists.");
```

When an error occurs that you want to hide from the user, throw a different kind of exception, perhaps named `InternalError`. You would want to **log** this and allow the program to continue, so the specific error is hidden from the user. If it prevents something from happening, you might want to throw up a generic error message. These would be *bugs* and you want to fix them as soon as possible.

e.g.:

```
throw new InternalError("Failed to connect to remote service");
```

All of the error messages can be stored (hard-coded) in the source where the exception is thrown. This is not necessarily a bad design practice - if you use a tool like [gettext](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php), you can easily translate all of these messages.

Comment: I like that idea, the only caveat is if there's multiple errors ideally I want to record the error an continue execution. Hence why I was using setError and getError. I check if the return is true, which means all actions were successful and if not I get the error. An action my be partially successful, and as a result I'd like to return false and use getError to get message indicating which part was unsuccessful. 

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Personally I think exceptions should be for internal only, like holding error log messages etc. If you start to mix the two you can end up in a mess with users getting system messages.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using log4j and log4cxx and logging to a syslogd.  Kiwi is a simple Win32 syslogger that will track your log messages and save them to a file.  Log4j / Log4cxx have configuration files that you can use to setup all your log levels or log message destinations (you can log to multiple places).

It takes so little effort to setup and use, and it works like a charm.

I haven't tried out [log4php](http://www.vxr.it/log4php/) myself.

Exceptions are good when you no longer want your program to continue executing.  Catch exceptions at a high level where you can accept the fall-out of failed executions.

Answer (score 1):

Review the **NerdDinner** tutorial on how to create validation routines before making a final decision:

http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part3.htm

The Validation part is about 2/3 of the way down the page.